# Exercise about minimal primes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I try to re-ask this question in a most precise way since it was closed.

> Let $k$ be a field, and let $R_{a,b}=k[x,y,z]/ (x^az,xy^b)$, for some positive integers $a,b$. I have to find a primary decomposition of $(0)$ and for which $a,b$ there are embedded primes.

Now since a decomposition is $(x),(x^a,y^b),(z,y^b)$, the associated primes are the respective radicals, i.e. $(x),(x,y),(z,y)$ (for any $a,b$). It is for this reason that I don't understand why the existence of embedded primes depends on $a,b$, and is not true that $(x,y)$ is always embedded, containing $(x)$.

Comment: A decomposition is $(x),(x^a,y^b),(z,y^b)$ **if** $a>1$. If $a=1$ one of these primary ideals is superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I$ is a monomial ideal, and we can find a primary decomposition in a straightforward way: $$(x^az,xy^b)=(x^a,xy^b)\cap(z,xy^b)=(x^a,x)\cap(x^a,y^b)\cap(z,x)\cap(z,y^b)=(x)\cap(x^a,y^b)\cap(z,y^b).$$
In particular, this shows that $\dim R_{a,b}=2$.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for my confusion but I'm quite new to this subject. So, to answer all the other question of the problem, the minimal primes over $I$ are $(x)$ and $(y,z)$ and a chain of maximal length is $(x) \subseteq (x,y)\subseteq (x,y,z)$. The last question was to find for which $a,b$ there are embedded primes in the decomposition: however $\sqrt {(x^a,y^b)}=(x,y)$, so independently of $a,b$ it seems to me that $(x)$ is always embedded. Is all ok?

Comment: The embedded prime are the minimal elements (with respect to inclusion) in the set of primes $\mathfrak p$ such that $\mathfrak p =\sqrt{\mathfrak q}$ for some primary $\mathfrak q$ of the decomposition. (In our case the set of such primes should be $\{(x), (x,y),(y,z)\}$).

Comment: Sorry I confused the terminology, the embedded primes are the non-minimal elements... Anyway I would say that $(x,y)$ is always embedded, where is the dependence from $a$?

Comment: There are two different primary decompositions: one for $a=1$, and another one for $a>1$. For $a=1$ the ideal $(x,y)$ is not associated.